# java lambda allmatch print value if not match

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Having a list of strings, if a string not start with a prefix, I would like to print it.
The result will be a boolean, if all strings start with the prefix.

Is there a way to do it in one row?

What is the correct syntax to combined this too :

```
 return words.stream()
        .allMatch(work -> word.startWith("ab"));

 words.stream()
        .forEach(word -> {
          if (!word.startWith("ab")) {
            System.out.print(word);
          }
        });
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Stream.peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)) to place an operation in the middle of the stream

```
static boolean testPrefix(List<String> words, String prefix) {
    return words.stream()
            .peek(word -> {
                if (!word.startsWith("ab")) System.out.println(word);
            })
            .allMatch(word -> word.startsWith(prefix));
}
```